# Create Pivot Table using PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table like this:

```
type    code    desc    store  Sales/Day  Stock
-----------------------------------------------
1       AA1     abc     101        3        6
1       AA2     abd     101        4        0
1       AA3     abf     101        4        3
2       BA1     bba     101        5        1
2       BA2     bbc     101        2        1
1       AA1     abc     102        1        4
1       AA2     abd     102        2        0
2       BA1     bba     102        4        2
2       BA2     bbc     102        5        5
etc.
```

How I can show the result table like this:

```
type    code    desc         Store 101             Store 102
                        Sales/Day | Stock    Sales/Day | Stock
--------------------------------------------------------------
1       AA1     abc        3          6         1          4
1       AA2     abd        4          0         2          0
1       AA3     abf        4          3         0          0
2       BA1     bba        5          1         4          2
2       BA2     bbc        2          1         5          5
etc.
```

Note:
Colspan is only display.

Comment: Why not using some reporting like `Jasper Report` or `Crystal Report`? It would be much easier rather than do all in query..

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query

Comment: @dwir182: User want to show the result in excel and send it with automatic email every day. So I create with query and get the data.

-sibert: Thanks, i will learn.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=34f525f51e2f94da1158e75b7eaeca7b)

**First way: `FILTER`**

```
SELECT
    type,
    code,
    "desc",
    COALESCE(SUM(sales_day) FILTER (WHERE store = 101)) as sales_day_101,
    COALESCE(SUM(stock) FILTER (WHERE store = 101), 0) as stock_101,
    COALESCE(SUM(sales_day) FILTER (WHERE store = 102), 0) as sales_day_102,
    COALESCE(SUM(stock) FILTER (WHERE store = 102), 0) as stock_102
FROM mytable
GROUP BY type, code, "desc"
ORDER BY type, code
```

Aggregating your values. I took `SUM` but in your case with distinct rows many other aggregate functions would do it. `FILTER` allows you to aggregate only one store.

The `COALESCE` is to avoid NULL values if no values are present for one aggregation (like `AA3` in store `102`).

---

**Second way, `CASE WHEN`**

```
SELECT
    type,
    code,
    "desc",
    SUM(CASE WHEN store = 101 THEN sales_day ELSE 0 END) as sales_day_101,
    SUM(CASE WHEN store = 101 THEN stock ELSE 0 END) as stock_101,
    SUM(CASE WHEN store = 102 THEN sales_day ELSE 0 END) as sales_day_102,
    SUM(CASE WHEN store = 102 THEN stock ELSE 0 END) as stock_102
FROM mytable
GROUP BY type, code, "desc"
ORDER BY type, code
```

The idea is the same, but the newer `FILTER` function is replace by the more common `CASE` clause.

---

**Notice** that "desc" is a reserved word in Postgres. So I strictly recommend to rename your column.

Comment: I think op want pivot.. See there are `store 101` and `store 102` in top..

Comment: See my demo. This is common way to pivot table. It is exactly your expected result

Comment: Thanks, it will be the second choice. Because, if there is a new store, i have to change the query again.

Comment: Yes in both cases you'll have to change the query. In the first you have to add 2 FILTER lines, in the second one you'll need 2 new CASE lines.

Comment: @S-Man Ok, I will remember. Thanks

Comment: @FadhelJMuhammad Thanks for accepting. Please do not forget to upvote as well (accepting shows that your problem is solved, upvoting is for the internal statistics of the respondent)